# LinkButton rendered inside a grid shows a horizontal scroll bar when length of text is big

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex3

I am trying to create links inside data grid cells and I am unable to remove the horizontal scroll bar

Here is my example

```
///////////////////////////////////////////
//GridExample.mxml - Main application
///////////////////////////////////////////

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<mx:Box id="myCustomBox" height="100%" width="100%" initialize="assignData();">


    <fx:Script>

        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.collections.HierarchicalData;

            [Embed("dialog_error.png")] 
            private var myImage:Class; 


            public function assignData():void {
                var retVal:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
                var hData:HierarchicalData = new HierarchicalData();
                var s:String = '[{"Property":"AA","Value":2,"RowIdentifier":"AA"},{"Property":"BB","Value":"Nice looking link","RowIdentifier":"BB"},{"Property":"CC","Value":"sdfgusgdfugadgfuasygdfgauidsguiasgdfugasuidfguiasg","RowIdentifier":"CC"}]';
                var pSets:Object = JSON.parse(s);
                var propertySets:Array = pSets as Array;
                for (var i:int=0;i<propertySets.length;i++) 
                { 
                    var item:Object = propertySets[i];
                    var arrayElt:Object = {Property: item["Property"], RowIdentifier: item["RowIdentifier"], Value: item["Value"]};
                    retVal.addItem(arrayElt);
                }

                hData.source = retVal;
                myGridId.dataProvider = hData;

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myGridId" 
                         variableRowHeight="true"
                         width="100%"
                         showHeaders="false" 
                         includeInLayout="{myGridId.visible}"
                         defaultLeafIcon="{null}"
                         >  


        <mx:columns >
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn  dataField="Property" headerText="Property" backgroundColor="#E5EFF5" width="0.4" wordWrap="true" />
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn  dataField="Value" headerText="Value" backgroundColor="white" width="0.6" itemRenderer="ExampleRenderer"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn  dataField="RowIdentifier" visible="false"/>
        </mx:columns> 


    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>      

</mx:Box>

</s:WindowedApplication>


///////////////////////////////////////////
//ExampleRenderer.mxml - ItemRenderer used
///////////////////////////////////////////

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<mx:Box xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" textAlign="center" creationComplete="renderNow()" >
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.controls.LinkButton;
        import mx.controls.Alert;


        private function renderNow():void {
            var dataObject:Object = super.data;
            var rowId:String = dataObject["RowIdentifier"];
            var label:LinkButton = new LinkButton();
            label.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
            label.percentWidth = 100;
            label.label = dataObject["Value"];
            label.setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy","off");
            label.setStyle("textAlign","left");
            label.setStyle("paddingLeft",3);
            this.addChild(label);
        }

        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            super.data = value;
            dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE));
        }

        private function mouseClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
            Alert.show("Clicked on a link");
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

</mx:Box>
```

The LinkButton produced nice links that can be clicked and in a web view it looks really good with a nice hover producing an underline (just like a link) etc but when the text is long, the horizontal scroll bar obscures the text itself. How do I get rid of the horizontal scrollbar (I have tried turning horizontalScrollPolicy off and that does not help). I do not mind if the extra text over and beyond the row length is hidden as I am going to add a tooltip anyway to every cell. Any help here is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the minWidth to 0 along with the percentWidth=100 fixed it.